# Camera wrong orientation?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created an empty 2D project - to try a tutorial from here

https://codeplanstudio.com/tutorials/block-adventure-game-tutorial/

(episode 2).

1. Added assets (graphics)
2. created Canvas
3. in the Canvas

   ```
   a. canvas rendering mode Screen Space Camera

   b. rendering camera set to Main Camera

   c. Canvas scaler: scale with screen size, Reference resolution set x:1920 y:1080, match 0.5
   ```
4. added UI image to Canvas
5. in image

   ```
   a. source image - an image from assets

   b. set native size (native size is width:1080 height:1920)
   ```

When I look at the scene, the camera has the same dimensions with the canvas, but inverted: what should have been height is width and what should have been width is height.

[image]

What I was expecting was this (as seen in a video tutorial):

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Reference resolution set x:1920 y:1080` sounds flipped then ... in general the camera automatically scales along with the dimensions of your GameView window ... there you can configure it to be ether Free (=> camera will have whatever resolution that window has) or can configure the exact dimensions you want to use

Comment: @derHugo the thing is even if I flip those values as x:1080 y:1920 - the image I get is exactly the same. Also I forgot to mention other settings as scale with screen size and Match - just edited the question and added those.

Comment: Are you sure the source image is orientated correctly?

Comment: the image is downloaded from the tutorial, apart from that it is 1080 width 1920 height.

Comment: @derHugo could you explain  how exactly would I set camera dimensions in game View?

Comment: on the top of the gameview where it says `Display 1` right next to it there you have a resolution dropdown .. the default is usually `Free Aspect` bu you can simply add your target resolution via the `+` button, give it a name and resolution and select that one

Comment: @derHugo thank you - that must be it! I manually added new resolution 1080x1920 (default was 1920x1080) and it worked - thank you very much !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your GameView on the top bar there is the `Display X` dropdown and right next to it a resolution dropdown.

Per default it is usually `Free Aspect` which means the camera resolution is whatever the resolution of the `GameView` window is.

[image]

Open the dropdown and click on `+` to create a new resolution option

[image]

Adjust it according to you needs e.g.

[image]

or using a dynamic resolution but fixed aspect ratio.

Now you can select it and no matter how the `GameView` window is scaled now it always keeps this fixed resolution (or aspect ratio) for the camera.